# Sum of values from 2 columns from 2 tables ignoring results equal 0

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
Table "credits":
id amount
1  8
2  7
3  2
4  1
5  5
6  4
```

and

```
Table "debits":
id amount
1  3
3  2
4  1
5  3
```

I need to get the total balance (credit-dedit) per id BUT leaving out balances=0. Ideally, something like this:

```
id balance
1  5
2  7
5  2
6  4
```

So far I have this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount) as balance,
FROM
(
    SELECT id, amount FROM credits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, -amount FROM debits
)
unified_table
GROUP BY id
```

but it is including the balances=0:

```
id balance
1  5
2  7
3  0
4  0
5  2
6  4
```

I tried:

```
SELECT id, SUM(IF( amount > 0, amount, 0)) as balance,
```

and also:

```
WHERE balance > 0
```

And other modifications but they are not working. I am running out of ideas. Please help, how can I leave out the balances 0? Thank you

Comment: add having balance>0  after group by id this should do it

Comment: wow THANK YOU MAN! it worked like a charm. Why would `where balance > 0` not work and `having balance > 0` does work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add having balance>0 after `group by id this should do it.

in the

> in the Where clause you can put condition only on the column of the table in the from clause using function will be accepted if you don't use group by because the function will be applicated on the row but with group by you are looking for the sum of the grouped rows so having will do it because you can put the column that are selected

```
select column_name, sum(..) as calculate  from table  group by column_name  having calculate > 0
```

calculate is column of result not the table joined 
and if you put the sum(..)>0 in where clause this will not be applicated on the group by but at the level of row.
sorry for my english ^^ but i think you get the idea

Comment: I do get the idea. Thank you very much for your help and time!

Comment: any time my friend ^^

Comment: can you please help me with this if you have time please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201475/sum-of-values-from-2-columns-from-2-tables-and-sorting-by-a-column

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (using [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.peterkropff.de/site/mysql/inner_join.htm)):

```
SELECT c.id, (c.amount - d.amount) balance
FROM credits c
INNER JOIN debits ON c.id = d.id
WHERE (c.amount - d.amount) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT 
  `credits`.`id`,
  (
    `credits`.`amount` - `debits`.`amount`
  ) AS balance 
FROM
  `credits`
  LEFT JOIN `debits` 
    ON `debits`.`id` = `credits`.`id` 
WHERE (
    `credits`.`amount` - `debits`.`amount`
  ) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

do like below

```
select id,sum(credits.amount-debits.amount)as balance
from credits 
inner join debits on credits.id = debits.id 
group by credits.id
having balance>0
```