# Sum of values from 2 columns from 2 tables AND sorting by a column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

Table "credits":

```
id | amount | type
1    8        1
2    7        2
3    2        1
4    1        1
5    5        3
6    4        2
```

and

Table "debits":

```
id | amount
1    3
1    2
3    2
4    1
5    3
5    1
```

I need to get the sum of all "id's" balances (credit-debit) and grouping it by "type". So far I have this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(amount) as balance,
FROM
(
    SELECT id, amount FROM credits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, -amount FROM debits
)
unified_table
GROUP BY id
```

But it just gives me the "id's" balances:

```
id | balance
1    3
2    7
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    4
```

Ideally, I need something like this:

```
type | balance
1      3
2      11
3      1
```

I tried to add the "type" column in the first "select" of the union, and then group by "type". But not working I think because table "debits" dont have column "type". How can I accomplish this? Thank you for your help

Comment: What means `But not working`?

Comment: What is the type in debits?

Comment: it is giving error. I think because table "debits" dont have column "type"

Comment: @Marko Juvančič "type" column is integer

Comment: What I mean is: there's no type column in debits table.

Comment: There is not type column in "debits" only "credits". Both tables are joined by the "id"

Comment: what is the relation between debits and credits   exactly is the debits with id = 1  is the credits of id = 1

Comment: for example from credit with id=1 were debited twice: 3 and 2, so balance is 3. credit with id=2 never was debited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
SELECT c.type, sum(c.amount - IFNULL(d.amount,0))
FROM credits c LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, sum(amount) FROM debits GROUP BY id) d
    ON c.id=d.id
GROUP BY c.type
```

The idea is to group the `debits` table first, and then join it with the `credits` table, which will result in a table that you can group by `type`

Comment: As the OP stated, The `credit` table is the main table. after all this is the place to take the type from

Comment: Yes, `credit` table is main table and this solution worked! Thank you everybody for your time! I could not be more thankful.

Comment: sorry for my comment this is the correct answer ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Type, Sum(Amount)
  FROM (
       SELECT C.Amount - ISNULL(D.Amount, 0) AS Amount, C.Type
         FROM Credits C
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id, Sum(Amount) 
                 FROM Debits 
               GROUP BY ID) D ON C.Id = D.Id
  ) A
 GROUP BY A.Type
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT  
    credits.`type`, 
    credits.`amount` - IFNULL(t_debit.`d_amount`, 0) AS balance 
FROM 
    credits, 
    (SELECT id, SUM(amount) AS d_amount FROM debits GROUP BY id)t_debit 
WHERE 
    credits.`id` = t_debit.`id` 
GROUP BY 
    credits.`type`;
```

First I select sum of amounts from `debits` table group by id and after I did another select query on the credits table where credit id match to debit id. I don't use UNION operator because the id's column in debits table is an foreign key.